# How to add swipe left and right animated appearing of view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to make a animated swiping like the one apple has on segues but for my view. I want when I swipe left to open a segue animated. Here is my view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX3ZE.jpg , I have the buttons on the top that are opening the segues but I want on swipe left or right to open the segues too. Here are the segues, right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWvaV.jpg, left: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1eB1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can add UISwipeGestureRecognizer for swiping to change the view.

```
let rightSwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rightSwipe))
    rightSwipeGesture.direction = .left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGesture)

@objc func rightSwipe() {
    // code to change view
}
```